# How do I finish cutting out this wheel well?

Tags: modifiers, vertices

So I've been studying shrinkwrap modifiers, I created a forming block, the shap I want to "shrinkwrap" to, I created the basic car form over it, cut out some doors by removing faces, now I'm trying to create a wheel well. I watched a video where they did something using another shrinkwrap set to project.. i'm really close, my circle is "shrinkwrapped" to the cars surface, but I can't "cut it out"....
[image]

Comment: did you join the objects?

Comment: yes. I did join them the circle is part of the mesh? in edit mode, its just not connected?

Comment: I definitely remember in the video I saw, joining was an important part before the cut was made.

Comment: hmm maybe you should aply the shrinkwrap?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the **Knife Project** command.

[image]

Basically you choose the cutting object, than the object to cut, enter in edit mode, put the camera perpendicular to the projection plane (if the object is shrinkwrapped you just have to avoid to make all the cutting geometry to be visible from the cam) and run the command.

It will also automatically select the inner faces of the cutting loop.

---

Another could be to use **boolean operations**.

From the cutting profile you have to create some faces and extrude them just of the amount needed to penetrate the object to cut. Than apply Boolean modifier set to Difference

[image]

Once applied, you should have the faces that belonged to the cutting object extrusion selected, ready to be deleted.

[image]

Comment: I'd really be interested a different way. that leaves me with jaggy edges, really bad.